# OutputStream issue in sslsocket on android lollipop

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-5.0-lollipop, sslstream

I've got an android SSL client communicating with a c# ssl server. I have noticed a strange behaviour on the sslsocket on android lollipop. When I send some data to the server eg. "Hello Server" the server reads only the first character out of the data I sent but when I try the same code on a device lower than lollipop the server reads the whole message in one go. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Bug in the server.  It should read everything presented to it.

Comment: @EJP well it does on devices lower than lollipop, because I'm using an example provided by msdn and it simply works with android devices lower than lollipop

Comment: I expressed myself poorly. It should keep reading until it has everything it needs. It should not rely on getting entire messages in a single read.

Comment: I know what you mean but it's strange how it would work flawlessly on kitkat and not on android lolipop.

Answer (score -2):

Just put dash(-) while making string. than u can write ur data to server. In ssl it read security type so u should write than blank or dash(-). If it will work pls let me know.

Comment: Come off it. Dash has no meaning to SSL or TCP. It is also a change in the application protocol. This is not going to work for any reason whatsoever.

Comment: This does not make sense at all